# TS Mapped Type: Conditionally remove certain key base on value

Tags: typescript

I'm looking for a solution to produce a mapped type that omit certain key base on the mapped key's value.

Concrete example:

I have an `option: Options` struct, where `Options` is an union type of shape:

```
{ type: DataType } or { type: DataType, params: DataParam }
```

Some elements of the union have `params` key and some don't. I want to produce such union utilizing mapped type. Currently I have this working solution ([Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOAFOAnOBbAzlAvFAbwCgoph0ATCALigDsIA3CVAbhLMogH0AjNWsVKkAlnWAtGcADa06AVwy8W7YVDETUU6QFU6I4LQBE2I1AA+UI1jOWTtq8BEBjANY2LVxgHtpR1VAAvuzBRESgkLAIcAAq4BA4+K4QIN4AZlGIKOjY7OHxUADyYE7edFgAYt6o8IhxkAA8MVAQAB4SdBQ4tbHxWAB8eIQcETRQMSFQAGRQABQ92ZhYANoxALot7RCdOAzMqBwA-ISBHIIcamBoS7QL19irawGkgQCUYfmRxaXlQ0JQyx69WgYkyvUgWDWtG+IjKlWqQPiDURkH6IUB0WBkNYQA)):

```
type DataParams = {
  trade: never;
  trade_bar: {
    interval: number;
    intervalUnit: "ms" | "s" | "m" | "ticks" | "vol";
  };
};


type DataTypes = keyof DataParams;

type OptionsForDataType<T extends DataTypes> = {
  type: T;
} & (DataParams[T] extends never
  ? {}
  : {
      params: DataParams[T];
    })


type Options = {
  [DataType in DataTypes]: OptionsForDataType<DataType>;
}[DataTypes];
```

But I'm not entirely satisfied with the ugly intersection + extends trick. Is there a better way to express such intention?

I was under the (probably wrong) impression that when `{ key: never }`, that key is effectively excluded from the struct, since nothing is subtype to `never`, nothing can be assigned to that key. Turns out this is not the case, which looks strange to me.

Comment: Not sure if better (instead of `never` checks if key `DataParams` map and simplifies the `Options`) https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOAVcEDOUC8UBEwBOcAJhDlAD64HEQD6ARnPjgNwBQoksCcACk3AC2GbAG82UKNRIMmALijjJkgJYA7YBHwA3OABsFagK6D6W9sqjrNO-QFU1K4ApzCylHGne5B3vCoBjAGsvClxtAHs9VgkoAF92BLYOVCgAeTBgFQi1NAAxCPx4RBRIAB4kKAgAD001Igxi5FQ0AD4sKEqauoaoIIgQCIAzbkR+QmFYgH5FKVQFJAAaKDABYQUm8aE0AG0kAF142IVROcgFo5SuDKyckXTM7NyCop5SiDKm97a2IA

Comment: @AlekseyL. Thanks for responding. But I still want to leave `{ trade: never }` as-is, cus in my use case I want to keep things in one place. I've edit my question to disambiguate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm kinda embarrassed that I didn't do my Google Diligence™️ thoroughly. Search ["mapped type exclude never value"](https://www.google.com/search?q=mapped+type+exclude+never+value) keywords and it takes me to [microsoft/TypeScript#23199](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23199), where people has the same doubt post the issue and got a solution.

So the digest to that issue thread is, my doubt is legit, the TS team also think `{ key: never }` should exclude the key, however due to some technical difficulty they cannot implement it.

Workaround is to create a utility type that filters desired keys, and apply it as an intermediate step. Solution [(Playground Link)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFUBcEsBtpgUwM4C4BQkCeAHRoAxOSRAJ0QBMBpRLZAHgBUA+UAXlAG9QBtABVDQAdqADWtAPYAzUIwC6qWfzmhEADxJCKyUEMQA3MqAD8ug0cUCAvj3FZpsuQG5MufAFE1AY1gBXCogAcuakRIiw2vQA8qwcnOigvFSCIkSwJOTUtAwxCqBRPFRy6Fbo6CAQyPheAIZVGNh4oAAiNZA1fDWkNQC2OnEJoJDdAYp6hqQuicM1AQD6AEZdivGJicIZ+jWwY749C2RTaxtkW7DgQgiKAER916AAPqDXyPdPt2-PMF6ir4-P+gksGuRysLjBZUa+Fa7UYbn6YkkMhhHS6vWQLlcTSiOBgEiECNWvBRcKawhabRqpJQeU8Pn8QRCYQiDCJ0zcihJbiOiRwaL6nMpnW6fR4XLwzkGVmYJTFlOpyElQA), taken from that issue and adapted to my use case, goes like:

```
// Utilities:
type FilteredKeys<T> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends never ? never : P }[keyof T];
type ExcludeNeverFields<O> = {
  [K in FilteredKeys<O>]: O[K]
}

// Use case:
type DataParams = {
  trade: never;
  trade_bar: {
    interval: number;
    intervalUnit: "ms" | "s" | "m" | "ticks" | "vol";
  };
};

type DataTypes = keyof DataParams;

type Options = {
  [DataType in DataTypes]: ExcludeNeverFields<{
    type: DataType;
    params: DataParams[DataType];
  }>
}[DataTypes];
```