Best solution to extract optional parameters based on conditional types
I am trying to create a client in typescript for the following endpoints:
/**
 * https://myapi.com/tokens/eth/${address}
 * https://myapi.com/tokens/security/eth/${address}
 * https://myapi.com/rank/eth/wallets/7d?orderby=pnl_7d&direction=desc&tag=snipe_bot
 * https://myapi.com/smartmoney/eth/balances/${userAddress}?limit=100&orderby=last_active_timestamp&direction=desc&tx30d=true
 * https://myapi.com/wallet_token_activity?wallet=${userAddress}&token=${tokenAddress}&limit=50
 */

This is the code I have:
type EthereumAddress = `0x${string}`

type ApiMethods = {

  getToken(): string

  getTokenSecurity(): string

  getRanking(args: { param: string }): string

  getBalances(args: { param: string }): string

  getActivity(args: { param: string }): string
}

type ApiPathsStruct = {
  [K in keyof ApiMethods]: {
    path: string
    hasAddress: boolean
  }
}

const apiPaths = {
  getToken: {
    path: '/tokens/eth',
    hasAddress: true
  },

  getTokenSecurity: {
    path: '/tokens/security/eth',
    hasAddress: true
  },

  getRanking: {
    path: '/rank/eth/wallets/7d',
    hasAddress: false
  },

  getBalances: {
    path: '/smartmoney/eth/balances',
    hasAddress: true
  },

  getActivity: {
    path: '/wallet_token_activity',
    hasAddress: false
  }
} as const satisfies ApiPathsStruct

type ApiPaths = typeof apiPaths

type Path<K extends keyof ApiPaths> = keyof {
  [T in ApiPaths[K]as T extends { hasAddress: true }
  ? `${T["path"]}/${EthereumAddress}`
  : T["path"]]: 0
}

type Payload<K extends keyof ApiMethods> = Parameters<
  ApiMethods[K]
>[0] extends undefined
  ? never
  : Parameters<ApiMethods[K]>[0]


function buildUrl<M extends keyof ApiMethods>(
  method: M,
  ...args: (ApiPaths[M] extends { hasAddress: true }
    ? (Payload<M> extends never
      ? [EthereumAddress]
      : [EthereumAddress, Payload<M>]
    )
    : (Payload<M> extends never
      ? [undefined?]
      : [Payload<M>]
    )
  )
) {

  let API_BASE = 'https://myapi.com'
  
  let address: EthereumAddress
  let payload: Payload<M>

  if (apiPaths[method].hasAddress && args[1]) {
    address = args[0] as EthereumAddress
    payload = args[1]
  } else if (apiPaths[method].hasAddress) {
    address = args[0] as EthereumAddress
  } else if (args[0]) {
    payload = args[0] as Payload<M>
  }
}

As you can see the buildUrl function gets quite messy, both in terms of its type and in terms of the conditional checks I need to extract the arguments.
I was wondering if there is a cleaner way I could employ to refactor my code to make it more readable, of if the endpoints being the way they are makes it difficult to achieve type safety.
More specifically, is there a better way to 'extract' the optional parameters based on the conditional type? Or is this an XY problem and I am employing the wrong solution to my problem? Thanks.
Playground
EDIT:
As pointed out, I could use function overloading such as in:
type AddressMethods = keyof {
  [K in keyof ApiPaths as ApiPaths[K] extends { hasAddress: true } ? K : never]: 0
}

type PayloadMethods = keyof {
  [K in keyof ApiMethods as Payload<K> extends never ? never : K]: 0
}

// Needs only address
function buildUrlWithOverloading<M extends Exclude<AddressMethods, AddressMethods & PayloadMethods>>(method: M, address: EthereumAddress): any
// Needs only payload
function buildUrlWithOverloading<M extends Exclude<PayloadMethods, AddressMethods & PayloadMethods>>(method: M, payload: Payload<M>): any
// Needs both
function buildUrlWithOverloading<M extends AddressMethods & PayloadMethods>(method: M, address: EthereumAddress, payload: Payload<M>): any
function buildUrlWithOverloading<M extends keyof ApiMethods>(method: M, addressOrPayload?: EthereumAddress | Payload<M>, payload?: Payload<M>) {

}

The problem is that this approach gives much worse intellisense help and autocompletion (as seen in the attached pictures) while adding 2 new helper types. So is it really better?



Just glancing at it I'd say you're trying to simulate function overloading with conditional types, but TS actually does have function overloading...

If I correctly understand what you are after here I think there is a much simpler way to do this with function overloads and a couple of helper types. My understand is that you have a collection of methods:

Some methods need an address
Some methods take a payload as argument
There is some overlap between 1 & 2.

So to that end:
// couple of helper types, courtesy of https://stackoverflow.com/a/64749429/3757232
type FilteredKeys<T> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends never ? never : P }[keyof T];
type ExcludeNeverFields<O> = {
  [K in FilteredKeys<O>]: O[K]
}
type EthereumAddress = string

type NeedsAddressMethods = {
  getToken(): string
  getTokenSecurity(): string
  getBalances(args: { param: string }): string
}

type NoAddressMethods = {
  getRanking(args: { param: string }): string
  getActivity(args: { param: string }): string
}

type ApiMethods = NoAddressMethods & NeedsAddressMethods

type HasPayloadMethods = ExcludeNeverFields<{
  [K in keyof ApiMethods]: Parameters<ApiMethods[K]> extends [] ? never : ApiMethods[K]
}>

type Payload<M extends keyof ApiMethods> = M extends keyof HasPayloadMethods ? Parameters<HasPayloadMethods[M]>[0] : never
type HasPayloadAndNeedsAddress = keyof HasPayloadMethods & keyof NeedsAddressMethods

function buildUrl<M extends keyof NeedsAddressMethods>(method: M): any
function buildUrl<M extends keyof HasPayloadMethods>(method: M, payload: Payload<M>): any
function buildUrl<M extends keyof NeedsAddressMethods(method: M, address: EthereumAddress): any
function buildUrl<M extends HasPayloadAndNeedsAddress>(method: M, address: EthereumAddress, payload: Payload<M>): any
function buildUrl<M extends keyof ApiMethods>(method: M, addressOrPayload?: EthereumAddress | Payload<M>, payload?: Payload<M>): any {
  const methodPayload = payload ?? typeof addressOrPayload === 'string' ? undefined : addressOrPayload;
  const address = typeof addressOrPayload === 'string' ? addressOrPayload : undefined;
  // do stuff
}

I simplified a few things, but this should give you the meat of what you're after. Edit the names of variables and the return type(s) of buildUrl to suit.
Playground

I edited the question adding a cleaner approach to your input. But the problem is that it gives significantly worse intellisense help. So can it really be considered a better approach?

@RiccardoPerego it depends, is this for a library intended for a currently unknown and possibly unbounded set of developers to work with? Or is it for an application being built by a small cohesive team? Because if it's the first one it's probably worth eating the complexity in the code to offer better intellisense and if it's the second the ease of maintenance is probably more important.

It's actually none. I'm trying to learn and still got a long way to go. Should I grow up to become a software engineer at a large tech firm, which approach would you reckon I would be using?

And should you answer that using function overloading is more popular in those environments, would you consider my version TS blasphemy? Or would it still be considered 'good code'? Sorry for the opinion-based questions but I am really keen to learn from a Senior Software Engineer.

The one that more closely resembles the type of work you are doing at that time. My job is writing shared TS libraries that get used by potentially hundreds of developers at the company I work for, so I take intellisense pretty seriously. That being said, I would probably choose "neither" and see if I couldn't refactor all of this to be a little more amenable to the type system, but without deeply understanding the use case I'm reluctant to try that with the code you posted.

@RiccardoPerego If I wrote something like your original version (and I very well might depending on the circumstances) I would probably at least annotate it with some comments about why I wrote it that way (if not a full-blown ADR). Function overloading is the more "obvious" way to do this and would not require a justification, but that doesn't mean it's always actually better :)
